# Remove quota from yaml

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

I'm ugins [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) to transformt this code

```
        let coor = `[ ${x}, ${y}, 0 ]`;

        rooms.push( {
            ...
            coordinates: coor,
            ...
        } );
```

I would wirte

```
  coordinates: [ 1, 2, 0 ]
```

But what I got now is the string with quotas:

`"[ 7, 3, 0 ]"`

This is how I write the file

```
fs.writeFileSync( `${id}.yml`, yaml.safeDump( rooms ), 'utf8', err => {
```

What kind of option should I do use?

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping a string to YAML, that, if written as a plain scalar (i.e. without quotes) would be interpreted as a YAML sequence. To prevent that from happening, you need to have quotes around the string.

In other words: because the first character of your string (`[`) has special meaning in YAML, the scalar needs to be quoted.

There is no way around this when you dump a string a string as you do. You can of course dump an array in flow-style and then you'll get `[ ... ]` without quotes, but when dumping a string, you'll be prevented from doing something wrong.

Comment: if I do like this:             let coor = [ 5, 12, 0 ];
then I got
`- 5
- 12
- 0`

Comment: That is the block-style, you need to dump them in flow-style as I wrote in my answer, to get that the style used in your original post. You can do that with the `flowLevel` parameter to `safeDump` (https://npm.taobao.org/package/js-yaml). Not that it is semantically different of course.

Comment: I moved to  js-yaml but with yaml.safeDump( rooms, {
        'styles': {
            'flowLevel': 1
        }

I still have the quotas

Comment: I have no idea how you came to the idea to pass that as parameter for `styles`, and not to `safeDump` itself (as the documentation indicates).

Comment: becuase the document speaks about it, plus with the `safeDump` do not change anything

Comment: The documentation also speaks about `noArrayIndent`, but you are not doing `yaml.safeDump( rooms, { 'noArrayIndent': { 'flowLevel': 1 })` for that reason. Just do `yaml.safeDump( rooms, { 'flowLevel': 1 })`  (don't forget the closing parenthesis).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193226/discussion-between-salvatore-di-fazio-and-anthon).